# Running Total C# on btnClick

Tags: c#, for-loop

Everything is working fine but I need to create a running total that will save all of the donations. It should display the total amount raised for the charity (that is, the total amount donated less all operating costs) for all donations up to that point. I know I need a while loop or do while loop so that the app runs and keeps adding the data. I just don't see why this code isn't producing the running total. I'm looking for help. Is there something I'm overlooking.

```
private decimal donationBFees = 0;

void deductOperatingCost(ref decimal afterFeesParam)
{
    afterFeesParam = afterFeesParam - (afterFeesParam  / 100 * 17);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String donationBeforeFees;
    decimal totalDonationRaised;

    donationBeforeFees = donationBox.Text;
    donationBFees = System.Convert.ToDecimal(donationBeforeFees);


    decimal afterFees = donationBFees;
    deductOperatingCost(ref afterFees);
    afterFeesBox.Text = afterFees.ToString("$###, ##0.00");

    decimal total = 0;

    //This is the for loop I'm using to get the running total
    for (int i = 0; i < afterFees; i++)
    {
        total += afterFees;
        totalDonationRaised = total;
        totalDonationsBox.Text = totalDonationRaised.ToString("$###, ##0.00");
    }
}
```

Comment: `total` is declared in the `Button_Click()` method.  As soon as that method exists the value of Total is lost.  If you want `total` to persist its value across multiple calls to `Button_Click()` then the variable needs to exist outside the scope of _just that method_

Comment: You can't iterate a `decimal` value `afterFees`... You'd need an array or a collection

Comment: You should have just [updated your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52884234/1070452) rather than posting essentially the same thing again

Comment: Yes that's true. I just thought that there was too much information in the description

Comment: @Fabjan Is that because the variable total is getting overwritten? It seems like the for loop is locking the system because when I have it in the code the other parts don't even work. Seems weird that a for loop at the bottom of the code would do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code below run correctly?

```
private decimal donationBFees = 0;

decimal deductOperatingCost(decimal afterFeesParam)
{
    return afterFeesParam - (afterFeesParam  / 100 * 17);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal donationBeforeFees = System.Convert.ToDecimal(donationBox.Text);

    decimal afterFees = deductOperatingCost(donationBeforeFees);
    afterFeesBox.Text = afterFees.ToString("$###, ##0.00");

    decimal totalDonationRaised = System.Convert.ToDecimal(totalDonationsBox.Text) + afterFees;
    totalDonationsBox.Text = totalDonationRaised.ToString("$###, ##0.00");
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt, this didn't work. Its conplaining about this, decimal afterFees = deductOperatingCost(donationBeforeFees);

Comment: Did you add `deductOperatingCost`? What is the error?